# TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have some very simple code that is triggered by a google form  (see http://goo.gl/lFHi3j)  that asks for 2 email addresses. The code works fine when the email address is hardcoded (see commented email below) but when I try and obtain the email using e.values (when the form is submitted) is get the following error

> Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined.
>   (line 3, file "Code").

I've searched this forum but can't find a solution to this problem. Can anyone please help.

```
    function onFormSubmit (e) {
//     var email_address_ = "pian1966@gmail.com";
       var email_address_ = e.values[1];

// Send the email
       var subject_ = "Andy's Report";
       var body_    = "Here is Andy's report...";
       MailApp.sendEmail(email_address_, subject_, body_, {htmlBody: body_}); 
    }
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Why do you expect `e.values` to exist?

Comment: im assuming (e) is an event... that means that e.target will contain the form... but it's still not just gonna give you 'values'... If you are referencing specific fields then use `var email_address_ = document.getElementById('unique_id_for_email_address_field').value;`

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I thought that e.values would exist because the email addresses I'm looking for are supplied by the user in the form. I thought that when "submit" is pressed, this script would be triggered and e.values would contain all the inputs provided by the user in the form. Isn't this how it worked with the previous version of Google forms?

Comment: Try putting a `console.dir(e)` as the first statement in `onFormSubmit` to find out what sort of form it takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the responses which all helped me find a solution to the problems I was having. Here's what I've discovered as I've worked on a solution:

1. The Google App Script must be created (as a blank script) from
   responses spreadsheet and NOT out of the form itself!
2. In Google Forms, the developer has the option of unlinking their
   responses spreadsheet and sending responses to new results
   spreadsheet. If this option is selected then a new script needs to
   be created from the new results spreadsheet and the code must be
   copied/moved into the new script. Of course this means that a new
   trigger must be created and the script needs to be authorized to
   run.
3. Once a user submits a form, they can be given the option to
   edit/correct their submission. Unless EVERY field is edited, the
   script thinks the unedited fields are blank and writes "undefined"
   into the resulting Google Doc. I've therefore disabled the "Edit"
   option in my form to get around this.
4. If the user skips over irrelevant fields (leaves them blank) then
   the e.values numbering order is thrown out. I have therefore made
   every field compulsory with the comment that the user enter 'n/a' if a
   field doesn't apply.

Having worked through these issues my form now works perfectly (albeit a little clumsily with all questions being compulsory). I would be very grateful if anyone has any suggestions on how to get around the Editing and and Blank Field problems.

(Thanks to TJ Houston for his original script)

Answer (score 4):

There is no `e.values[1]`.

That is the answer to the question as to why you are getting that error.

Do a `console.log(e)` and familiarize yourself with what `e` consists of by looking at the log results in a browser debugger.

From there you can determine for yourself if e.values even exists as an array. Then go from there.